# What would be the role of a Java designer script project in a VB6 to C# conversion?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, computer-science

In my job, I am currently trying to wrap my head around a VB6 to C# conversion project for a large tool that someone else built a long time ago.

Something I have come across is an unfinished Java project called "Designer", which generates ***.designer.cs files before the parsing program is ran on the VB files to build .cs files. I cannot understand what the purpose of these .designer.cs files generated by the designer is, as to my (limited) understanding .designer.cs files are usually created automatically by whatever IDE you are writing your C# in. Here is a sample

```
namespace RAUI
{ 
  partial class frmAbout
  { 

  private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
    components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }

  }

  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
    this.cmdOK = new GGControls.DRGButton();

    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    this.Text =    "Test";
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(156, 129);
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 106);
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimizeBox = false;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    this.cmdOK.Name = "cmdOK";
    this.cmdOK.Text =       "&OK";
    this.cmdOK.CausesValidation = false;
    this.AcceptButton = this.cmdOK;
    this.cmdOK.TabIndex = 3;
    this.cmdOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72,72);
    this.cmdOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81,27);
  }
}
```

I think that this very simple sample just creates controls and properties necessary to implement the c# code, but I don't understand why there is a need to have a very large and complicated designer script as part of the conversion process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could understand why you would generate the designer files in a conversion, but wouldn't VB already *have* designer files? Do they not exist in your VB project?

Comment: No, the VB project contains strictly forms, .frx and .ctl files, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The designer file has InitializeComponent(), which sets up all of your controls on the form.  This method is called from the form constructor.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I believe I understand the purpose of a designer file in itself, what I don't understand is why there is a need for a Java designer project to actually generate these designer files in a VB6 to C# conversion, and what it is doing that could not be done automatically with properly translated .cs files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in saying that *.designer.cs files are *usually* created by the IDE. However, generating them yourself makes sense here.

To understand why, you have to realize what that file *actually is*. The IDE takes all the stuff you do on the actual forms designer (hence, designer.cs) and stuffs it into a generated code file that has all the code necessary to create your form.

You could actually make a form without the designer at all, the code is just so messy that it makes sense to do two files (and `partial` classes).

So, in this conversion, since you don't already have designer files to do a straight conversion, generating them based on the other existing files seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Plus one. The VB6 equivalent of a form designer is the top half of the frm and the frx file. They contain control and form properties. They are created by the VB6 IDE. A thorough VB6 to C# conversion is likely to involve converting these form/control definitions into a c# designer.